# How to show div based on Bootstrap dropdown/custom select?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show different divs based on the option I select on a Bootstrap dropdown menu. However, even if it seems easy, I can't find a proper example of this. How should I change the JS, if I have to change it? 
This is my code so far:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Homepage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
  <div class="form-row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-auto my-1">
      <label class="mr-sm-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelect">Preference</label>
      <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
      </select>
      <div>
  <p id="1">Text1</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p id="2">Text2</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p id="3">Text3</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p id="4">Text4</p>
</div>
    </div>


  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this fix your problem ??

```js
$('#inlineFormCustomSelect').change(function() {
  $('.child-item').removeClass('show'); // hide all visible
 $('#' + $( this ).val()).addClass('show'); // Show what is necessary
});
```

```css
.child-item {
  display: none
}

.show {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script>

    <title>Homepage</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <div class="form-row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-auto my-1">
                <label class="mr-sm-2" for="inlineFormCustomSelect">Preference</label>
                <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormCustomSelect">
                    <option selected>Choose...</option>
                    <option value="1">One</option>
                    <option value="2">Two</option>
                    <option value="3">Three</option>
                    <option value="4">Four</option>
                </select>
                <hr>
                <div>
                    <div id="1" class="child-item ">
                      <div class="flourish-embed flourish-chart" 
                        data-src="visualisation/2406500" 
                        data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2406500/embed">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p id="2" class="child-item">Text2</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p id="3" class="child-item">Text3</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p id="4" class="child-item">Text4</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </form>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it does, thank you! But I have a problem with it if I try to embed  a custom graph, like a div inside the div: <div class="flourish-embed flourish-hierarchy" data-src="visualisation/2406500" data-url="https://flo.uri.sh/visualisation/2406500/embed"><script src="https://public.flourish.studio/resources/embed.js"></script></div>

Comment: It should not be a problem. Do you have the API documentation to what you are trying to achieve ??

Comment: I guess not, I'm just trying to embed another div with a graph I created! The full code is here: https://codepen.io/dreamtheater96/pen/PoPLjVX

Comment: If you check the codepen you can see it doesn't work for option one (graph) and that the others, when clicked, then are appended one after another

Comment: Modified the snippet. Have a Look. You might wanna run in your solution as things can get blocked. Keep an eye on for the console for errors

Comment: in the codepen console it is saying `"Flourish: could not find anything to embed"`. Also move the `script` tag inside the `head`